# Entry not Filling Parent Stack Layout

Tags: maui

I am building an entry form with a caption column and a value column. The caption column contains a label and the value columns contains a HorizontalStackLayout which might have an Entry and a search button right next to it. I have the HorizontalStackLayout set to FILL which it does fine. I have the Entry also set to FILL which it does NOT?

```cs
//IF THIS IS  A TEXT FIELD
if (cv.GetType() == typeof(Entry)) { ((Entry) cv).HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
}

//SET CONTROL'S DYNAMIC VIS SETTING
cv.IsVisible = visible;

//IF THIS FIELD IS READONLY
if (trx.is_field_readonly(c)) {
  cv.IsEnabled = false;
}

//ADD CAPTION TO GRID
grid.Add(caption, 0, c);

//USING STACK LAYOUT IN CASE WE NEED TO ADD A SEARCH BUTTON
HorizontalStackLayout hz = new HorizontalStackLayout();
hz.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGoldenrodYellow;
hz.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
hz.Add(cv);

//ADD CONTROL TO GRID
if (trx.is_field_lookup_field(trx.data_field_list[c])) {
  ImageButton search_button = new ImageButton();
  search_button.WidthRequest = 32;
  search_button.HeightRequest = 32;
  search_button.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
  search_button.Source = "Resources/Images/search.png";
  search_button.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGray;
  search_button.Padding = 5;
  hz.Add(search_button);
}

//ADD STACKLAYOUT FOR CONTROL(S)
grid.Add(hz, 1, c);
```

The appearance is this:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to get the Entries to fill the HorizontalStackLayout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add to question declaration of grid, and ColumnDefinitions. I assume grid does not have that same yellow background, so it is definitely from horizontal stacklayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fill` doesn't do what you expect, when inside a StackLayout.

The Obsolete `FillAndExpand` does. See Maui discussion [LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand is obsolete](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7346). Though that is talking about `..AndExpand` on `End`, its a similar issue on `Fill`.

Either:

- use `FillAndExpand` (even though it is obsolete).
  Or:
- Use a Grid instead (no stacklayout). This lets you control expansion by ColumnDefinition `*` vs. `Auto`. In your case, you'll define the columns differently, depending on whether the row has BOTH Entry AND Image.

Since you are already in a Grid, [I think] the most performant solution, because it avoids nesting layouts, is to add a third column, then use `ColumnSpan=2` when you want Entry to fill the space that would be used by Image:

```cs
var grid = new Grid()
{
    ColumnDefinitions =
    {
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },  // or whatever you have now.
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }
    }
};

...

bool hasImageButton = trx.is_field_lookup_field(trx.data_field_list[c]);
grid.Children.Add(cv, 1, c);
if (!hasImageButton)
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(cv, 2);
if (hasImageButton)
{
    ...
    grid.Children.Add(search_button, 2, c);
}
```

Comment: Never even thought about using ColumnSpan! Works like a charm with one subtle change which was Grid.Children.Add did not have an overload with the ColumnSpan argument. Had to use Grid.SetColumnSpan on the control then it worked GREAT! Good stuff ToolmakerSteve!

Comment: Good! I've fixed column span setting.